# how to change selected index of tabbar item when pushing UIViewController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am pushing one view controller to another view controller but when I am pushing the tabbar item index is not changing.How can I change selected index when pushing view from one to another.Thanks in advance.

Comment: tabbar item index ?.. you mean tab controller selected index right?

Comment: Please clarify the question some what more it's ambiguous. Need some more detail to give proper answer.

Comment: read this documentation well https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: how many viewcontrollers do you have? more than 6?

Comment: when I am pushing view controller from 0 index of tabbarcontroller to another view controller which has 1 index . after pushing from 0 to 1 ,I want to show selectedIndex as 1. - Wolvorin

Comment: @newDev Did you even look at the documentation? tabBarController.selectedIndex will give you the index of the selected tab, and tabBarController.selectedViewController will give you a pointer to the view controller at the active tab.

Answer (score 6):

Try ,

```
[tabBar setSelectedItem:[[tabBar items] objectAtIndex:index]];
```

or

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];
```

Answer (score 6):

This line may help someone

**`[self.parentViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];`**

Comment: That helped me :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Here index 0 is refering to first tab of your tabbarcontroller.

Comment: I am using Three20 in my application

Answer (score 0):

simple example for `UITabBarController` for You..only create three `UIViewController`.this code work fine :)

**appDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecoundViewController.h"


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    FirstViewController *fView;
    SecoundViewController *sView;
    ViewController *viewCon;

    UITabBarItem *tbItem1;
    UITabBarItem *tbItem2;
    UITabBarItem *tbItem3;

     UINavigationController *FnavCon;
     UINavigationController *SnavCon;
     UINavigationController *navCon;

     UITabBarController *tbCon;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic,retain)FirstViewController *fView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)SecoundViewController *sView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UINavigationController *navCon;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITabBarController *tbCon;
@property(nonatomic,retain)ViewController *viewCon;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UINavigationController *FnavCon;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UINavigationController *SnavCon;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITabBarItem *tbItem1;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITabBarItem *tbItem2;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITabBarItem *tbItem3;

@end
```

**appDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize fView,sView,navCon,tbCon,viewCon,FnavCon,SnavCon,tbItem1,tbItem2,tbItem3;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds ]];

    self.viewCon=[[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.navCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewCon];
    self.navCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.viewCon.title=@"First View";

    self.fView=[[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    self.FnavCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.fView];
    self.FnavCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    self.fView.title=@"Secound View";

    self.sView=[[SecoundViewController alloc] init];
    self.SnavCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.sView];
    self.SnavCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.sView.title=@"Third View";

    UIImage *img1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Australia.gif"];
    self.tbItem1=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First Page" image:img1 tag:1];
    self.viewCon.tabBarItem=self.tbItem1;

    UIImage *img2=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cameroon.gif"];
    self.tbItem2=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Secound Page" image:img2 tag:2];
    self.fView.tabBarItem=self.tbItem2;

    UIImage *img3=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Canada.png"];
    self.tbItem3=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Third Page" image:img3 tag:3];
    self.sView.tabBarItem=self.tbItem3;

    NSMutableArray *viewArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [viewArr addObject:self.navCon];
    [viewArr addObject:self.FnavCon];
    [viewArr addObject:self.SnavCon];


    self.tbCon=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tbCon.viewControllers=viewArr;

    [self.window addSubview:tbCon.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```